# R SHINY Graficos Interactivo(o animado)

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, shiny

Hola buenos días compañeros, tengo una consulta. Como puedo lograr que mis gráficos  generados en shiny con ggplot2 puedan recibir una especie de animación, es decir, suponiendo un gráfico de barras quiero hacer que al pasar el mouse por encima de una columna este me muestre su valor. Aquí un ejemplo: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/lego-viz/

A continuación mi código

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    tabPanel(   
        "Nuevos Beneficios",
        h3("Cantidad de nuevos beneficios mensual"),                                  
        selectInput(inputId = "IAñoDesde", label = "Año desde", choices = c(2016,2017,2018,2019,2020), selected = 2018),                         
        selectInput(inputId = "IAñoHasta", label = "Año hasta", choices = c(2016,2017,2018,2019,2020), selected = 2019),                            
        plotOutput("nuevosBenef"))
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$nuevosBenef <- renderPlot({ 
        result <- Altas[year(Altas$Periodo) >= input$IAñoDesde & year(Altas$Periodo) < input$IAñoHasta, ]
        ggplot(result, aes(x = Periodo, y = TPINDDVAL, fill = mes, group = 1)) + geom_line(color='steelblue', size=3) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_minor_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%B %Y") + 
        labs(x = "Periodo", y = "Cantidad", subtitle = "Subtitulo") + 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias librerías que te permiten hacer eso que deseas, la del ejemplo que muestras es  `highcharter` pero también está `plotly`. Aquí te muestro las modificaciones que debes hacer en tu codigo para lograrlo

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel(   
    "Nuevos Beneficios",
    h3("Cantidad de nuevos beneficios mensual"),                                  
    selectInput(inputId = "IAñoDesde", label = "Año desde",
                choices = c(2016,2017,2018,2019,2020), selected = 2018),                         
    selectInput(inputId = "IAñoHasta", label = "Año hasta",
                choices = c(2016,2017,2018,2019,2020), selected = 2019),                            
    plotlyOutput("nuevosBenef"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$nuevosBenef <- renderPlotly({ 
    result <- Altas[year(Altas$Periodo) >= input$IAñoDesde & year(Altas$Periodo) < input$IAñoHasta, ]

    p <- ggplot(result, aes(x = Periodo, y = TPINDDVAL, fill = mes, group = 1)) + 
      geom_line(color='steelblue', size=3) +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
                   date_minor_breaks = "1 week",
                   date_labels = "%B %Y") + 
      labs(x = "Periodo", y = "Cantidad", subtitle = "Subtitulo") 
  })
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo siempre compartir un ejemplo reproducible de los datos que estás utilizando para que el que te ayude pueda comprobar lo que te recomienda antes de mandartelo.